# Restarting a thread after it has been left

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have thread which contains a loop

```
while(isRunning){
}
```

`isRunning` is a Boolean variable with the value `true`, when some clicks on a button it gets `false` and so it leaves the loop and the `run()` function of the thread.

I want to create another button that on click it will reenter the `run()` function.

I am not sure if when I leave the `run()` function the thread dies or just stops.
I have tried using `thread.run()` but it didnt work.

Also I have looked for an answer in other's people questins about this matter but nothing seemed to help me. Thanks for the help

Comment: Add the language tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your thread runs to its end, it stops.
It will remain there for you to collect its return status until the thread is cleaned up.

To restart within the same thread, you need an extra control flow.
For instance:

```
while (restarted) {
    while (isRunning) {
    }
    // Wait for a restart or end click
}
```

That is what so called *worker threads* in a *thread pool* do, which are intended for maximum performance.

But logically, you will probably simply want to create a new thread object and start that one.

```
new Thread(p).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

When a thread is finish processing it's code, There's no way of restarting it. You can either:

1. Create a new thread and pass the `Runnable` to that thread.
2. If you need to use that `run()` method often, use an `Executor`. You can use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`, which will supply you with a worker thread. (Reusable thread).

   ```
     class Example {
          static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

          static Runnable run = new Runnable() {
               public void run() {

               }
          };

          public static void main(String[] args) {
               //anytime you wanna run that code..
               executor.execute(run);
          }
     }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Please read through java concurrency tutorial. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Just Maybe, guarded blocks might be useful for your case but your case is a little vague to recommend anything specific.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html